# A moment problem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-problem

What is the p.d.f. for the moments $m_n=1/n$ ?

(They are obtained from $\int_0^1 x^n/x\ dx $, but clearly $1/x$ is not a p.d.f. on $[0,1]$)

Comment: Well, we have $$m_2-m_1^2 = \frac{1}{2}-1^2<0, $$ which is impossible for moments of a probability distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee I see. Then what if I consider the moments say $m_n=1/(10n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that there exist $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}_0$ satisfying

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \frac{a}{n} \tag{*} $$

for all $n \geq N$. Then it is easy to see that $a \geq 0$ and that $\mu$ is supported on $[-1, 1]$. Moreover, we know that $\nu(\mathrm{d}x) = x^N  \mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ satisfies:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x)
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{n+N} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)
= \frac{a}{N+n}, \qquad \forall n \geq 0. $$

Since the [Hausdorff moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem) has a unique solution, the above condition determines $\nu$ as $\nu(\mathrm{d}x) = ax^{N-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$. Therefore, we conclude

$$ \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \frac{a}{x}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Of course, this cannot be a probability measure.